# Arabic Strings doesn't want to stay inline in the correct order

Tags: javascript, notepad++, atom-editor, arabic, arabic-support

Hellow,

**Edit** I found a "[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53369921/4657432)" on my own (see below), I'm sorry for asking so hasty.

I developed a script and got the request to translate it in the arabic language. He also sends me all the respective strings, which I need. And after some affort, I could copy and paste it in my Editor (Notepad++, ATOM), but I CAN'T write or paste it inline.

```js
datetime.strings.register("ar", {
    months: [
        "يناير", 
        "فبراير",
        "مارس",
        "أبريل",
        "مايو",
        "يونيو",
        "يوليو",
        "أغسطس",
        "سبتمبر",
        "أكتوبر",
        "نوفمبر",
        "ديسمبر"
    ],
    days:   [
        "الأحد",
        "الإثنين",
        "الثلاثاء",
        "الأربعاء",
        "الخميس",
        "الجمعة",
        "السبت"
    ],
    shorts: [
        "أحد",
        "إثن",
        "ثلا",
        "أرب",
        "خمي",
        "جمع",
        "سبت"
    ],
    time:   [
        "ساعة",
        "دقيقة",
        "ثانية"
    ],
    header: [
        "إختر الشهر",
        "إخنر السنة",
        "إختر العقد",
        "إختر الوقت"
    ]
});
return datetime;
```

The above code is in the right order (I hope at least), but when I'm now trying to "minify" this a bit it reverse the complete order:

```js
datetime.strings.register("ar", {
    months: [
        "يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "أبريل", "مايو", "يونيو", "يوليو", "أغسطس", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر"
    ],
    days:   [
        "الأحد", "الإثنين", "الثلاثاء", "الأربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة", "السبت"
    ],
    shorts: [
        "أحد", "إثن", "ثلا", "أرب", "خمي", "جمع", "سبت"
    ],
    time:   [
        "ساعة", "دقيقة", "ثانية"
    ],
    header: [
        "إختر الشهر", "إخنر السنة", "إختر العقد", "إختر الوقت"
    ]
});
```

That's really annoying and the "main" problem is: My script gets also compressed with jsCompress, which is subject to the same issue. So my Question: Is there ANY way to minify multiple arabic strings without losing the order of it?

I tried

- to remove the spaces manually,
- to "regexp" the spaces between the strings (using ATOM and N++)
- multiple compression and minifier tools

but nothing worked :/.

Sincerely,
Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah,

Nevermind. Its just a "Presentation Issue" of the editor. So it's in the right order, but it just gets displayed wrong (RTL doesn't "stops" on the quotation marks).

Sorry for asking, I'm stupid.

Sincerely, Sam.